# How to upgrade Castle.windsor from version 4 to version 5.0.1

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, castle

While upgrading Castle.Windsor to version 5, I found out that the PerWebRequest is removed from LifestyleTypes enum.

In my application I am registering the components with different lifestyles like this

```cs
private static void RegisterComponents(LifeStypleType defaultLifestyleType) {
    container.Register(Component.For<IProjectService>()
             .ImplementedBy<ProjectService>()
             .LifeStyle.Is(defaultLifestyleType));
}
```

On another page I am creating the Container like

```cs
_windsorContainer = RegisterComponents(LifestyleType.PerWebRequest);

_windsorContainer2 = RegisterComponents(LifestyleType.Singleton);
```

Is there any way to use LifestyleType.PerWebRequest in Castle.Windsor version 5?

Comment: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/systemweb-facility.md

Comment: @qujck I have seen this solution but the problem is  Register Component asks for a LifeStypleType defaultLifestyleType,and based on that it is registering the component with it...Using LifestylePerWebRequest() will hardcode it, I need some generic solution

Comment: If I'm write that `RegisterComponents` is a method you own why not change it to take a custom version of `LifeStyleType` that you define and register each item accordingly?